# Windows 8 Metro focus on grid

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

I'm trying to make a simple windows 8 metro game using c# and xaml. I've been having trouble getting the KeyDown event to fire. I think this may be because the grid does not have focus. If this is the case, how would I give the grid focus in my code? Thanks for helping.

Here's my code:
The grid in xaml

```
    <Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" 
      KeyDown="Grid_KeyDown" KeyUp="Grid_KeyUp" x:Name="myGrid"
      >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock FontSize="30" Margin="10" x:Name="statusBox">Status</TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
```

and the event handler in c#

```
    private void Grid_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        statusBox.Text = "Key down";
    }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hook the event at the [CoreWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.core.corewindow.aspx) level instead of the grid level.  In your C#, do something like ...

```
CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().KeyDown += Window_KeyDown;
```

Where Window_Keydown is a method in place of where you currently have Grid_KeyDown.

Comment: I'm getting this error when I try to build.

Error 1 No overload for 'Window_KeyDown' matches delegate 'Windows.Foundation.TypedEventHandler<Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow,Windows.UI.Core.KeyEventArgs>' 

If I understood correctly that line should go in my constructor and I should replace Grid_KeyDown with Window_KeyDown.

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out. I needed Window_KeyDown to take a KeyEventsArgs instead of a KeyRoutedEventsArgs. Thanks for your help.

Comment: THanks for this, I wonder how many other people have followed the samples from http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Input-3dff271b and had it not work. Wonder why you can't catch the keyboard up/down from the Grid element.

Comment: insanely frustrating trying to get something like this to work ... i'm a seasoned .net and wpf developer, it shouldn't be so hard. thanks for the answer. The MSDN examples are PRECISELY WRONG on the topic (telling you to handle the event at the grid level which i never got to work).